# How can I make a working Kernel with less than 2Mb?

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation, kernel, size

Ok so here's my problem: for a school project I need to compile a working Kernel with size equal or lower than 2Mb, we need to build it from a custom virtual machine our teacher gave us using "make menuconfig" with an old version of Kernel (I belive 4.4), the default config results is a 4.8Mb file that i managed to lower to 2.8Mb, since its virtual machine I don't know how to check the "hardware" to  leave only the especific settings, when I asked the teacher only said "remove AMD options" and he didn't tell us what options are important for the Kernel to work, I've been trying for 2 days and I can't get any lower than 2.8Mb without causing a panic error when booting the sistem, it seems my classmates couldn't either, can anyone give some hints? the only requirement is to the system to boot and ask for user and password. I aplologise for any mistakes as english isn't my first language and my dispair isn't helping either.

I've removed all drivers I could exept for the keyboard ones, I tried to set everything I could to modules, i removed all AMD options as the teacher told us and set everything i could to better compression.I don't know what else is importantas we only had 2 classes where half of the time was waiting for the kernel to compile.

Comment: Maybe try to compile for 32 bits instead of 64?

Comment: didn't work: panic error on boot

Comment: "*I tried to set everything I could to modules*" -- That does not reduce the memory footprint of the kernel, but rather the image size.  So exactly what is the requirement? "*I've removed all drivers I could ...*" -- "Drivers" is but just one of several top-level menuconfig selections. What did you do for other sub-menus, e.g. Networking, Filesystems, Crypto. and Security? Did you review the **.config** file for configuration selections that seem expendable/unnecessary?